# Over which schemes can there exist non-trivial G_a bundles?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, principal-bundles

The group scheme G_a here is the one-dimensional additive group.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Principal Ga-bundles on a scheme X, in any of the Zariski, etale, or flat topologies, are classified by the coherent cohomology group H^1(X,OX).  For a smooth complex projective variety, this is the antiholomorphic component of the de Rham group H^1(X,C), which is a topological invariant.  So (in this smooth Kahler setting) the existence of nontrivial Ga-bundles depends only on the topological type of X.

I omitted some underscores for typesetting reasons.

Comment: You can escape the underscores with a backslash so that they don't cause a problem (i.e. type `\\_` to get `_`). Better yet, instead of typing `H^1(X,O\\_X)`, you can type `H<sup>1</sup>(X,O<sub>X</sub>)` to get really pretty-looking output.